# How to receive two values over i2c and parse in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, i2c, lcd

I have two arduinos, first arduino is for read the sensores and first lcd, second arduino is for second lcd.
Now I would like to make two values were sent to another Arduino by i2c

My sender code:

```
  byte senderArray[] = {batteryVoltage, temperatureC}; //12V, 23*C
  Wire.beginTransmission(4); // transmit to device #4
  Wire.write(senderArray,2); // sends
  Wire.endTransmission();    // stop transmitting
```

and here receive code:

```
void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(4);                // join i2c bus with address #4
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
}

void loop()
{
  delay(100);
}

void receiveEvent(int howMany)
{
  byte index = 0;
  int array[2];
  while(Wire.available() > 0)
  {
    array[index] = Wire.read();
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Battery: " + array[0]);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Temp: " + array[1]);
  }
}
```

How to display in the first line `batteryVoltage` in the second `temperatureC`?

EDIT:
Temperature result displays only 23, before sending the i2c was full output of 23,478, how to display the full result on the second Arduino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't concatenate a string and a number, you're mixing data types. Replace:

```
lcd.print("Battery: " + array[0]);
```

with:

```
lcd.print("Battery: ");
lcd.print(array[0],DEC);
```

etc...